# Password Protected PDF cannot be opened DOMPDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf

I created the password protection using the following code,

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf(array('enable_remote' => true));
$dompdf->loadHtml($html_print);
#(Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
#Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();
#PASSWORD PROTECTION
$dompdf->getCanvas()
    ->get_cpdf()
    ->setEncryption(1234, 5678, ['print', 'modify', 'copy', 'add']);
#Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream($filename);
#SAVE THE FILE TO SERVER
$output = $dompdf->output();
$filename =  $filename.'-'.time().'.pdf';
file_put_contents('../documents/'.$filename, $output);
```

It works perfectly when I download the file.

Before download I save this file in server also. But when I try to download the file later, then it is not open with correct password. It works smoothly if I didn't set password protection

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You should use ob_end_clean() before $dompdf->stream($filename);

Comment: @Danny It not worked

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. There is a key on the encryption info array called "p" that they refer to as the "p-value". When the PDF is streamed that p value changes from 252 to -4. The part of the code that does this has a comment of:

> and the p-value needs to be converted to account for the twos-complement approach

Because that p value changed during the first output the second time the pdf is output it is written to the file with an incorrect value.

The way I see it, you have 2 workarounds. The first is to output the PDF to a file first and then write your own code to echo that file to the browser or you can reset the p value between the stream and output as shown below:

```
#PASSWORD PROTECTION
$cpdf = $dompdf->getCanvas()
    ->get_cpdf();

$cpdf->setEncryption(1234, 5678, ['print', 'modify', 'copy', 'add']);

#Output the generated PDF to Browser
$infoB4 = $cpdf->objects[$cpdf->arc4_objnum]['info'];
$dompdf->stream($filename);

#SAVE THE FILE TO SERVER
$cpdf->objects[$cpdf->arc4_objnum]['info'] = $infoB4;
$output = $dompdf->output();
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: It worked. But the image in pdf is not showing why ?

Comment: There is no way for me to know that as I don't have the full html you are trying to convert. I would not have thought it would have anything to do with my workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf->getDomPDF()->getCanvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption("viewer_password", "my_password");
```